# AngularJS - Why is the DOM not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, what I am trying to do is add a "stack" - a basic JS object - into an array called `cardStacks`, declared the `stackCtrl` function. I've read that the controller in AngularJS is not supposed to do very much, nor do you want the manipulation of DOM elements done the controller. So what I have done is create a "save" directive which, as you could probably guess, adds a new "stack" into `$scope.cardStacks` (if the object is not being edited)

Everything seems to work ok, up until when the template is supposed to update. `console.log()` reveals that objects are going into an array, but because the template is not being updated, I can only guess it is not `$scope.cardStacks`.

Can somebody give the following a look and tell me why the template is not listing the "stacks" in the template?

Consider the following:

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="stackCtrl">
    <stackeditor></stackeditor>
    <p>Stacks:</p>
    <ul class="stack-list" ng-repeat="stack in cardStacks">
        <li><a href="#">{{stack.title}}</a>
            <span class="stack-opts"> (<a href="#" ng-click="edit=true">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>)</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Template for the stackeditor tag/directive:

```
<div>
    <span class="button" ng-click="show=!show">+ New</span>
    <form ng-show="show" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="stackTitle" required/>
        <button class="button" save>Save</button>
        <button class="button" reset>Cancel</button>
        <div ng-show="error"><p>{{error}}</p></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function stackCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cardStacks = [];
    $scope.stackTitle = "";

    $scope.addStack = function(title) {
        var newStack = {};
        newStack.title = title;
        $scope.cardStacks.push(newStack);
    }

    $scope.removeStack = function($index) {
        console.log("removing Stack...");
    }

    $scope.editStack = function(element) {
        console.log("editing Stack...");
    }
}
```

Directive:

```
fcApp.directive('save', function() {
    var linkFn = function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function() {
            if (typeof $scope.stackTitle !== 'undefined' && $scope.stackTitle.length > 0) {
                if ($scope.edit) {
                    $scope.editStack(element);
                } else {
                    $scope.addStack($scope.stackTitle);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.error = "Your card stack needs a title!";
            }
        });
    });

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linkFn
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using $apply:

```
 $scope.cardStacks.push(newStack);
 $scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.cardStacks;
 }
```

Rendering might be the problem..... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The save function would be better in stackCtrl and then use ng-click in the template to call it.

You are right that manipulating the DOM in the controller is bad practice, but you are just updating an object in the controller - angular is sorting out the DOM which is fine.